# Split a string into two based on char location

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I need to split a string into string based on the location of a character. So that:

str1 = "hello?world" is str1 = "hello" and str2 = "world"

This is what I have so far:

```
    char    str1[100] = "hello?world";
    char    str2[100];
    char    *p;

    p = strpbrk(str1, "?");
    strcpy(&str2, p);

    strcspn(str1, '?');
```

I get errors when trying to copy the characters after 'p' to str2.  There has got to be a better and functional way. Can someone help me out? Many thanks...

Comment: `strcpy(&str2, p);` should be `strcpy(str2, p);` (well, `p+1`, since `p` points to the `'?'` and you want the things after, if I understood correctly). But that should cause no error. What errors do you get?

Comment: @DanielFischer Removing the '&' fixed the error for me. And yes I did need p+1. I guess I was much closer than I thought because I have it working now. Thanks!

Comment: That's odd (unless the error was a compilation failure due to `-Werror`). Although `&str2` is a `char (*)[100]`, the address of `str2` is the same as the address of `str2[0]`, which you'd get if you pass `str2`. So except in some esoteric implementations where pointers to different types have different representations, `strcpy(&str2, p)` should cause a warning, but work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
strcspn(str1, '?');
```

is an error, `strcspn`'s second parameter is a `const char*`, passing a character constant there is almost certain to cause undefined behaviour and a segmentation fault (Your programme is very unlikely to have the address 63 (ASCII value of '?') in its address space, and if it has, it's unlikely to point to a 0-terminated character array).

```
p = strpbrk(str1, "?");
strcpy(str2, p+1);
```

ought to work. If you want to end `str1` at the '?', `*p = 0;` overwrites the '?' with a 0. But of course generally, you should verify that `strpbrk` doesn't return `NULL` before using `p`.

Answer (score 3):

`&str2` is a pointer to an array `[100]`. You should indeed use the adress of `str2`. Moreover, the second parameter of `strcspn` should be `"?"` (a null-terminated string) instead of `'?'` (a single character).
Besides, the following code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char s[] = "hello?world"; /* source string */

char s1[100] = ""; /* first part */
char s2[100] = ""; /* second part */

char *tmp = strchr(s, '?');

if (tmp != NULL) {
    *tmp = '\0';
    strcpy(s1, s);
    strcpy(s2, tmp+1);
}

puts(s1);
puts(s2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtok()](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/strtok.html).  Follow the link to see an example.

Do something like this:

```
   char    src[] = "hello?world";
   char    str1[100];
   char    str2[100];
   char    *p;

   p = strtok(src, "?");
   strcpy(str1, p);

   p = strtok(NULL, "?");
   strcpy(str2, p);
```

Comment: `src` should be an array instead of a pointer, because `strtok` modify its argument. It can cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know so much stdlib strings functions but you can do this (your strings will be "secure", i mean you will not have to allocate too much bytes but just the bytes needed that's why the code will be a bit long):

```
int main()
{
  char *tmp;
  char *s1;
  char *s2;
  char delim;
  int i;
  int j;

  tmp = strdup("hello?world");
  delim = '?';
  i = 0;
  while (s1[i] != delim)
   i++;
  j = 0;
  s1 = malloc(i + 1);
  while (j < i)
   {
    s1[j] = tmp[j];
    j++;
   }
  s1[j + 1] = '\0';
  j = 0;
  i++;
  while (tmp[i])
   {
    i++;
    j++;
   }
  i = strlen(tmp) - j;
  s2 = malloc(j + 1);
  j = 0;
  while (tmp[i])
   {
    s2[j] = tmp[i];
    j++;
    i++;
   }
  s2[j + 1] = '\0';
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Why don't you use `for` loops?

Comment: I've learned code in my school and we were not allowed to use it (as break, switch, printf and all of derivatives(?)) and were "trained" to use system calls and put char by char. So my C code can be strange for self-educated coders. My apologies if this can be long or strange for C expert